# Angular 2 NgModel vs Inputs and Events

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel, angular2-inputs

Can I use **NgModel** for interaction of the components or use only **inputs** and **events**?

**NgModel** should only be used in forms?

Comment: This question is too general.  You should make it specific.

Answer (score 1):

`ngModel` can be used when a `ControlValueAccessor` is provided for components. Angular provides `ControlValueAccessor` implementation for `<input>` elements out of the box.

Comment: @rinukkusu no need to delete your answer just because I also posted one.